# make checkbox do something only if another checkbox is checked (android)

Tags: android, checkbox

I'd like to make an activity that does some arithmetic depending on which checkboxes the user checks. I want some checkboxes to do addition *only if* another checkbox is checked, but I can't seem to check whether a different checkbox is checked from within the onCheckedChange method.

Here is the relevant part of my xml code:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbox_affective_dx"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/cbox_affective_dx"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/cbox_other_dx"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/cbox_other_dx"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

And here is the code I'm trying to use. As you can see I'm trying to add or subtract to the person's CFIscore depending on what they click. For the second checkbox, I only want to add or subtract to their score if the first checkbox is clicked. Otherwise I want it to do nothing. Eclipse is telling me that cbox_affective_dx cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
public class Checklist extends Activity {

int CFIscore = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);

    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbox_affective_dx);


    //On checked change listener
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            switch(buttonView.getId()){
                       case R.id.cbox_affective_dx:
                           //add 2
                           if (isChecked) {
                               CFIscore += 2;
                           } else if (isChecked == false) {
                               CFIscore -= 2;
                           }
                       break;
                       case R.id.cbox_other_dx:
                           if (isChecked) {
                               if (cbox_affective_dx.isChecked == false)
                                   CFIscore += 1;
                               else if (cbox_affective_dx.isChecked == true);
                           } else if (isChecked == false) {
                               if (cbox_affective_dx.isChecked == false)
                                   CFIscore -= 1;
                             else if (cbox_affective_dx.isChecked == true);

                           }
                         break;
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Simply find it and check whether it's checked:

```
CheckBox my_conditional_checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_conditional_checkbox_id);
if (my_condicional_checkbox.isChecked()) {
  // Do the stuff you need
  ...
}
else {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, my first checkbox is not checked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```